# How to optionally add material autocomplete in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to be able to optionally add autocomplete to an input.

Currently I have tried adding an `*ngIf` to the mat autocomplete tag but it raises errors because the input has the `matAutocomplete` property and is looking for the autocomplete component. I have also tried setting `matAutocomplete` to null when I want autocomplete off but this did not work.

Here is what I tired:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ebz9m-bw56h9?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.html

But I get:

```
Error: Attempting to open an undefined instance of `mat-autocomplete`.
```

This is how I want it to work:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ebz9m-umwj6h?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html

But without having to duplicate the input and form field tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The suggested "hack" works great if you always have the autocomplete component but sometimes don't have items for it. But it sounds like you want to create a custom component based on MatFormField and MatInput that can optionally use a MatAutocomplete. I've done this and there is no way around ngIf on the form field unless you use a future version of Angular Material v6. See https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11096 (my issue). They will be fixing this in Angular Material v6 via a new directive option to disable the autocomplete - `matAutocompleteDisabled`. When released, you can do this:

```
<input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matAutocompleteDisabled]="slide.checked">
```

So if `auto` is null, you won't get any errors.

Comment: hmmmm. The docs say the property is called [autocompleteDisabled]. It didnt work. I also tried [matAutocompleteDisabled] and it still didnt work. Apparently it still hasnt been implemented as of 6.0.2

Comment: @Curtis - Yes - as I said, _future_ _version_ - they _will_ _be_ fixing this. If you look at the issue you'll see the fix has not been merged to master.

Comment: Works great as of v9.x [matAutocompleteDisabled]="!(dataSvc.profile$ |async).userProfileSettings.showCompanyLookup"

Answer (score 0):

With a little hack you could simply replace the suggestions by an empty array when the slide is checked :

```
<mat-autocomplete  #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let state of (slide.checked ? [] : (filteredStates| async)) " 
[value]="state.name">
...
```

[Here is an edit of your stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50394876)